# Resume rendering?

Tags: rendering, animation, file-format

Is there a way you can resume renderings with cycles in AVI JPEG Format? Like if you wanted to stop your computer and give it a break and then start off the next time where you ended it? I don't know, it's just a question I've been asking my self a long time

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18266/workflow-to-convert-rendered-images-to-video

Comment: It's for reasons like this that it's recommended to [render to an image sequence first](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4881/599).

Comment: Oh ok I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, so just render each frame separately and use them in an image sequence when rendering the movie. That way you can pause the rendering any time you wish, and simply change which frame your starting from when you begin again.

Comment: You should absolutely never render in a video file directly. Always render into an image sequence first, then make a sequence of your rendered images and compress into a video format from there. ^ This is the exact reason to do this. If you break the render or need to render just a single frame to clean it up a bit, you don't have to render the _entire_ animation again. Both of these answers describe it well enough.

Answer (score 3):

To do the rendering in different sessions, render as an image sequence first. Make sure you disable the Overwrite option on the render output, that way the frames that are already rendered will be unaffected, no need to change the start point.

[image]

Once you are finished rendering all of the frames of your scene compile the image sequence into a video format.