# Save animation after rendering

Tags: rendering, animation, export

I rendered my animation, but with "png" as output type for the image. Now I have the rendered animation in Blender (I can see it with Ctrl+11) and 250 png images in a folder. How do I get a video I can export from that?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/52230/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15142/599, and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18266/599

Comment: Link 2 and 3 are not duplicates of this one but link 1 might be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Video Editor, Add the PNG images to the track
Set your render options for whatever video codec you want to use 
set your audio options if applicable and render animation.